# Find all occurrences of bytestrings in a python code snippet

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse python snippets, some of which contains bytestrings.
for example:

```
"""
from gzip import decompress as __;_=exec;_(__(b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xcbYmc\x02\xff\xbd7i\xb3\xdaJv\xdf\xdf\xaf /I\xf9\xbar\xc6%\x81@\x92k\x9c)\x16I,b\x95Xm\x87\x92Z-$\xd0\x86\x16\x10LM~{N\x03\xd7\xc6\xd7\x9e%\xa9\xa9PE/\xa7\xcf\xbeuk\xd3\xacm\xdd"\x94\x1b\'\xa5\xda\x04"H\x17\xae\xe3t\xf4\xcdn\x03\xa9/&T>\x13\xdbu\g=\x9f\x13~\x11\xf6\x9b\xd7\x15~\xb2\xe7\xbc\xe6\xc2K\xb8\x18\x03\xfd|[\x7f\xe8\xb8I;\xf0\xf1\x93\xec\x83\x8eo15\x8dC\xfc\xc6I\xf1\xfd\xf5r\x8f\xeb\x0f\xd7\xc53#\xa8<_\xb2Py\xbe\xe1\xde\xff\x0fk&\x93\xa8V\x18\x00\x00'))

x = b"\x1f\x8b\x08"

y = "hello world"
"""
```

Is there a regex pattern I can use to correctly find those strings?

I have tried implementing a regex query myself, like so:

```
bytestrings= re.findall(r'b"(.+?)"', text) + re.findall(r"b\'(.+?)'", text)
```

I was expecting to receive an array

```
[b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xcbYmc\x02\xff\xbd7i\xb3\xdaJv\xdf\xdf\xaf /I\xf9\xbar\xc6%\x81@\x92k\x9c)\x16I,b\x95Xm\x87\x92Z-$\xd0\x86\x16\x10LM~{N\x03\xd7\xc6\xd7\x9e%\xa9\xa9PE/\xa7\xcf\xbeuk\xd3\xacm\xdd"\x94\x1b\'\xa5\xda\x04"H\x17\xae\xe3t\xf4\xcdn\x03\xa9/&T>\x13\xdbu\g=\x9f\x13~\x11\xf6\x9b\xd7\x15~\xb2\xe7\xbc\xe6\xc2K\xb8\x18\x03\xfd|[\x7f\xe8\xb8I;\xf0\xf1\x93\xec\x83\x8eo15\x8dC\xfc\xc6I\xf1\xfd\xf5r\x8f\xeb\x0f\xd7\xc53#\xa8<_\xb2Py\xbe\xe1\xde\xff\x0fk&\x93\xa8V\x18\x00\x00', b"\x1f\x8b\x08"]
```

instead it returns an empty array.

Comment: That's the key phrase: you're trying to *parse* Python. So use a Python parser, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a job for regular expressions, but for a Python parser.

```
import ast

code = """
...
"""

tree = ast.parse(code)
```

Now you can walk the tree looking for values of type `ast.Constant` whose `value` attributes have type `bytes`. Do this by defining a subclass of `ast.NodeVisitor` and overriding its `visit_Constant` method. This method will be called on each node of type `ast.Constant` in the tree, letting you examine the value. Here, we simply add appropriate values to a global list.

```
bytes_literals = []

class BytesLiteralCollector(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Constant(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, bytes):
            bytes_literals.append(node.value)

BytesLiteralCollector().visit(tree)
```

The documentation for `NodeVisitor` is not great. Aside from the two documented methods `visit` and `generic_visit`, I believe you can define `visit_*` where `*` can be any of the node types defined in the [abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) presented at the start of the documentation.

You can use `print(ast.dump(ast.parse(code), indent=4))` to get a more-or-less readable representation of the tree that your visitor will walk.